# ASP.NET MVC 5 "View or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I know I'm not the first to post this error, but it seems slightly different.  I have a web site that I'm developing in VS 2015.  When I hit F5, everything looks great in IIS Express.  When I create a new IIS 10 site pointing to that exact same folder with a .NET 4.5 Integrated App Pool, I get the "View or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."  The controllers are invoked, but somehow it can't find any view.  My views are named based on the controller actions and work perfectly in VS.  I've added full permissions for the specific App Pool, DefaultAppPool, IIS_ISURS and Local Service users for the folder.  It seems like it must be a permission thing, but the error doesn't help to troubleshoot it.  I also installed Glimpse, but I'm not seeing any way to get more details through that either.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check if the views are there at server?

Comment: It's actually the same machine and same folder even.  The exact same files in the exact same place.  I just pointed IIS to my working project folder.  I have another project on my machine where I do the exact same thing and it works fine.  I'm not seeing how it's different from the working project.

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but it was clearly a permissions issue.  I moved the folder elsewhere and was able to make it work (one folder for IIS and VS).  I wish I knew which user/permission made the difference since it seemed to be the same...